# install xenserver 6.2 on 3ware 9750 raid5

Tags: xenserver, citrix, drivers, 3ware, kernel-modules

I would like to install XenServer 6.2 (kernel 2.6.32) on a raid5 managed by a 3ware 9750 controller. The XenServer installer doesn't recognize the raid5 and i think i have to load a driver for the 3ware 9750 4i controller.

I found a download [here](http://www.lsi.com/channel/support/Pages/Download-Results.aspx?productcode=P00060&assettype=Driver&component=Storage%20Component&productfamily=RAID%20Controllers&productname=3ware%20SAS%209750-4i)

but there is only source code in this archive. I have no suitable machine to compile this driver.

Is there any way to get the new server installed without compiling the driver on another machine?

**UPDATE 2013-08-24:**

I load the DDK VM as mentioned in the answers. It was possible to run `make` against the module sources (3w-sas-2.6.32.tgz see [download](http://www.lsi.com/channel/support/Pages/Download-Results.aspx?productcode=P00060&assettype=Driver&component=Storage%20Component&productfamily=RAID%20Controllers&productname=3ware%20SAS%209750-4i)) and ended up with these files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    268 Aug 24 09:02 .3w-sas.ko.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  30573 Aug 24 09:02 .3w-sas.mod.o.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38796 Aug 24 09:02 .3w-sas.o.cmd
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Aug 24 09:02 .tmp_versions
-rw-r--r-- 1 8004  345  60502 Dec  3  2009 3w-sas.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 8004  345  14029 Dec  3  2009 3w-sas.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 266688 Aug 24 09:02 3w-sas.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3611 Aug 24 09:02 3w-sas.mod.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  57960 Aug 24 09:02 3w-sas.mod.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 209900 Aug 24 09:02 3w-sas.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 8004  345    393 Dec  3  2009 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    730 Aug 24 09:02 Makefile.xen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Aug 24 09:02 Module.symvers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     44 Aug 24 09:02 modules.orde
```

I'm not shure how to build a XenServer Driver Repository. Additional the [documentation](http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/20640-102-489043/ddk-1.0-5.5.0-en_gb.pdf) tells to compile a module for kdump too. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted LSI support and they came up with the solution (at least providing the driver) within 24h. Nice!

[XenServer 6.2 kernel 2.6.32.43-0.4.1.xs1.8.0.835.170778xen](http://mycusthelp.info/LSI/_cs/AnswerDetail.aspx?inc=8335)

Answer (score 1):

The intention of distributing drivers like this is that you can compile them against your specific kernel sources (version and patches) and headers, targeting your machine.  Otherwise it would be necessary to make many, many binary distributions.  Unless you can find a suitable compile of the module (built against the XenServer 6.2 2.6.32 kernel), the answer is no.

If the hardware you are using is supported I'd expect citrix will have a package published.  Otherwise you must compile it and install it yourself.

Comment: I tried compiling the driver but i failed to setup make. see http://serverfault.com/questions/522151/xenserver-6-2-yum-repository

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the xenserver DDK.

http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/20640-102-489043/ddk-1.0-5.5.0-en_gb.pdf

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenserver/product-software/xenserver-62.html

It creates a VM which will enable you to build appropriate kernels.

How you do that, I'm not 100% sure.  The examples are very limited.  I'm trying to figure this out myself so that I can add infiniband support through a supplemental disk.
.

Comment: did you succeed? I failed compiling for kdump and building the repository...

Comment: Yes to an extent (infiniband drivers were broken in that build).  Basically I copied the sources from the kernel (on the source ISO) and followed the DDK driver examples.  I managed to build the .ko files ok but had a few problems with the layout.  I didn't spend much more time on it as I'm on other priorities at present but hope to come back to it soon.