# XenServer 6.2 Yum Repository

Tags: centos, yum, xenserver, citrix, rpm

I installed a clean XenServer 6.2 from the ISOs provided [here](http://www.xenserver.org/overview-xenserver-open-source-virtualization/download.html). I want to compile a driver against this system and need to install make and sources and so on.

If I do `yum install make` I get

```
[root@xenserver-2 driver]# yum install make
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist
http://updates.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.2.0/domain0/mirrorlist error was
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: citrix
```

The default repo location shipped with the installation just doesn't exist! Can anyone tell me the right location so I can update my /etc/yum.repos.d/Citrix.repo file?

My /etc/yum.repos.d/Citrix.repo looks like

```
[citrix]
name=XenServer 6.2.0 updates
mirrorlist=http://updates.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.2.0/domain0/mirrorlist
#baseurl=http://updates.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.2.0/domain0/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://updates.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/RPM-GPG-KEY-6.2.0
enabled=1
```

I also have the following repos /etc/yum.repos.d

- CentOS-Base.repo
- CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
- CentOS-Media.repo
- CentOS-Vault.repo

which are all disabled. If I enable the [base]-repo in CentOS-Base.repo I can install make. But can I also use the needed sources from this repo instead of citrix-repo? Is it safe at all to use these disabled repos?

Comment: I would not recommend using a CentOS repository with XenServer. Run CentOS if you want to use the CentOS repository...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you open [that URL](http://updates.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.2.0/domain0/mirrorlist) in the browser? (*I can.*) Does you server need to use a proxy to get out to the web? You may need to configure Yum for it.

Another option would be to create a local repository from the ISO you already have. Loop mount your ISO and change the `baseurl` to `file:///path/to/loopmount/Packages`. Now you can use Yum to install from a local source. You won't get updates, obviously, but at least you can install missing packages. For instances where you may have dozens of dependencies this will be much quicker.

The `baseurl` path should be the directory on the ISO which contains the `repodata` subdirectory. On CentOS this is the root, but I am not sure about XenServer. Red Hat has a 'Server' subdirectory for example.

```
mount -o loop xenserver.iso /path/to/loopmount
```

Comment: ok, the URL works now. It didn't when I wrote my question. So thanks for the update and your iso mount suggestion. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way.  You don't install the DDK into your dom0.  It becomes a virtual machine when you import it via XenCenter.
Once running, it includes everything necessary to build your device driver.

Comment: Why the downvote? you don't compile drivers in dom0, use the DDK VM provided by citrix.